# C++ Convert Encodings between character sets

Tags: c#, c++, .net, encoding

Suppose I have some bytes that are encoded in ANSI, and I want to convert them to UTF-8 bytes, how would I do that?

In C#, we have the [Decoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.decoder?view=netcore-3.1) class.

I can do this:

```
Decoder decoder = detectedEncoding.GetDecoder();
char[] array = new char[];
decoder.GetChars(chunk, 0, size, array, 0);
byte[] utf8ResultBytes = new byte[newSize];
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(array, 0, size, utf8ResultBytes, 0);
```

in C# to convert the files bytes which are any encoding into UTF-8 bytes.

Is there any way in C++ to convert from a **wide range** of encodings into UTF-8, and UTF-8 back into a **wide range** of encodings? Also, suppose I read of a chunk of a file, and then try to convert that file, which let's say is UTF-16, into UTF-8. The chunk might be in-between a **multi-byte character boundary**. How would I handle that for a wide range of encodings in C++?

I'm also open to library suggestions.

Comment: Support for multiple character encodings in the standard C++ library leaves much to be desired. Most applications that need to do this will use some external software library.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Do you have a library suggestion?

Comment: [libiconv](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) comes to mind immediately. There's also a project specialized for [windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm). Unfortunately recommendation quesitons are _off-topic_ here.

Comment: @Sam I doubt that's what's the OP is looking for.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks, I will check it out!

Comment: First of all, C# doesn't do *any* encoding/decoding, just like C++. The .NET framework does it, just as there is probably some C++ library that would do the same.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that. I should' ve been clearer